# Bug in drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I created a custom drawable for a button and found that if I share the drawable between an array of button, any button I press within the array of button will cause the last button in the array to be appear to be pressed as well. Here is the code...

```
//xml code for stage button
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/stage_button_selected"></item>
<item android:state_pressed="false" 
android:drawable="@drawable/stage_button_deselected"></item>
</selector>

//xml code for stage_button_selected
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" 
android:bottom="5dp">
<shape android:shape="oval" android:innerRadius="5dp">
<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"></solid>
<stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" 
android:width="2dp"></stroke>
<corners android:radius="5dp"></corners>
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>

//xml code for stage_button_deselected
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" 
android:bottom="5dp">
<shape android:shape="oval" android:innerRadius="5dp">
<solid android:color="@android:color/white"></solid>
<stroke android:color="#dddddd" android:width="2dp"></stroke>
<corners android:radius="5dp"></corners>
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>`

//android code
Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.stage_button, null);
for(int ctr=0; ctr<btnStage.length; ctr++){
GridLayout.Spec specRow = GridLayout.spec(specStage[ctr][0], 1);
GridLayout.Spec specCol = GridLayout.spec(specStage[ctr][1], 1);
GridLayout.LayoutParams lp = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(specRow, 
specCol);
btnStage[ctr] = new Button(MainActivity.this);
btnStage[ctr].setBackground(drawable);
btnStage[ctr].setText("Stage " + stageNo(ctr));
btnStage[ctr].setWidth(btnWidth);
btnStage[ctr].setHeight(btnHeight);
final String temp = stageNo(ctr);
btnStage[ctr].setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
ss_gridLayout.addView(btnStage[ctr], lp);
}
```

The solution to the problem is to create an array of drawable for use of the array of buttons, however it doesn't make sense that I cannot share the drawable between the array of buttons without it causing an unwanted effect...

Comment: You should see if calling [setBackgroundResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundResource(int)) directly solves it.

Comment: move `Drawable drawable = ...` to the `for` loop